# Оффлайн карты для Qt

Tags: c++, qt, карты, геолокация

Требуется для десктопного приложения использовать оффлайн-карты. Может кто-что посоветует, везде только примеры в режиме онлайн, либо оффлайн(только тайлы для osm). Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Используй тайлы osm . лучше не найдешь.

Comment: хотелось бы помимо тайлов еще xml данные использовать, но как я понял в оффлайн-режиме это невозможно, только тайлы

Comment: XML файлы это обычные текстовые файлы. Никто не запрещал  ими пользоваться при этом. Можешь загнать geojson в простргес. Но это ещё его тащить в проект